# Glittering or Shining Effect on Button

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-view

I have an `ImageView` which i want it to have shining effect every 3 or 4 secends. i've searched a lot but most of them was about writing a selector for that button and adding a bitmap around that button , but my desire is shining my whole `ImageView` or Button shines like turning light comes and go on a Medal.any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make the button animation yourself. The guide below shows how to make an animation drawable but you will have to do all the artwork for it. You could also try to use a gif or animated png as your button source but I don't know if android can render those properly. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html